# "cannot find symbol" error in netbeans ( Java Netbeans 6.5 )

Tags: java, netbeans

For my final project in introduction to Java, I decided to do a Mastermind Peg Game.

This is the submit button code:

```
private void submitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    Integer guess1, guess2, guess3, guess4;
    Integer rightnumber = 0, rightposition = 0;

    guess1 = Integer.parseInt (firstInput.getText());
    guess2 = Integer.parseInt (secondInput.getText());
    guess3 = Integer.parseInt (thirdInput.getText());
    guess4 = Integer.parseInt (fourthInput.getText());

    //Values are compared to the actual guess. 
    //(THIS IS WHERE I GET THE FOLLOWING ERROR: 
    //"cannot find symbol, symbol : variable answerdigit, 
    //location: class finalproject.Singleplayer"

    if ( guess1 == answerdigit[0]);
    {
        rightposition = rightposition + 1;
    }
}
```

This is the Start button. Here, the 4 digit answer/code is produced.

```
private void startButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                            
    // Declare variables for 4 digit answer, guess for each number
    Integer one, two, three, four;

    //Generate random number between 1 and 6 for each digit in the answer
    int[] answerdigit = new int[4];

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        answerdigit[i]=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
    }
}
```

I get an error:

```
cannot find symbol, symbol : variable answerdigit, location: class finalproject.Singleplayer
```

I don't understand what the error means.

Comment: You used a variable that does not exist inside the scope of the method submitButtonActionPerformed(...).  Read up on Java Variable Scope for a refresher on what the error means: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

Answer (score 2):

`answerdigit` is not accessible because you have declared it somewhere & it is only accessible to that local scope, for accessising it else anywhere you have to declare it in class

e.g.

```
class cls
{
 int[] answerdigit;
//your remaining code
}
```

you have declared it in

```
private void startButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
```

and accessing it in

```
private void submitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
```

thats why it is giving error.

Comment: Oh Yea! Ima Genius! jk jk, would've spent hours without your guy's valuable advice.

Answer (score 1):

You have a variable scope problem it seems: answerdigit is declared local to the startButtonActionPerformed method and thus only visible inside of this method and simply doesn't exist elsewhere. If you want to use this variable elsewhere in the class, then the array variable, answerdigit, must be declared in the class.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and advice. I will try to declare it in the class and see if I come up with a solution. (Will probably be back later with future problems *shudders*)

Comment: Please do read through the FAQ before you post more questions like this one.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Will do, I now know that making  a thorough search of all questions is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

`int[] answerdigit = new int[4];` should be in the scope of the class not in the scope of `private void startButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)` this method!

Just put `int[] answerdigit = new int[4];` this statement out of the method and your code will be fine... :)

Comment: I believe I've resolved this problem. To all answers, thank you very much!